# model value null when passed from angular post service

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am working on AngularJs with MVC , I am having a silly issue while passing model to MVC controller.

If I Debug the code .. data is  there in object till I make ajax post call.. but when I  check on controller everything becomes null.

Here is my code

AngularController

```
$scope.loginUser = {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        typeofUser: "ExternalUser"
    }

var onLoginComplete = function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        };

        var onError = function (reason) {
            $scope.error = "Could not fetch the data.";
        };

        DataService.validateUser($scope.loginUser).then(onLoginComplete, onError);
```

Now DataService

```
 var baseurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
            var validateUser = function (model) {
                return $http.post(baseurl + "Account/Login/" + model)
                                .then(function (response) {
                                    return response.data;
                                });
            }
```

and Model class in MVC

```
public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string TypeofUser { get; set; }
    }
```

Now you can below image that before making post call to controller , object has values..
[image]

But after going to controller , all values are null

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post parameters are not correct. Replace `+` with `,`.

```
return $http.post(baseurl + "Account/Login/", model)
```

You can read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#shortcut-methods).

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```